# How to copy paste Xcode warnings?

Tags: xcode, error

Is there a way to copy paste the content of this warnings in Xcode ?

[image: xcode error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  If you go to the Issue Navigator (<kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd>), you'll see a list of build warnings and errors.  You can select one from the list and hit <kbd>cmd</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.  You'll get something like this:

> /Users/dave/Developer/Cocoa/EmptyFoundation/EmptyFoundation.m:180:15:{178:2-178:6}{178:2-178:7}: warning: conversion specifies type 'unsigned long long' but the argument has type 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wformat,7]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's possible in Xcode 4.  Just click the warning (or error), then press <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.  It will copy the file path as well, but the warning/error text will be at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Click on your error or select the section and on your Apple Keyboard, tap the following : ⌘ + C to copy it and ⌘ + V to paste it.