# How to copy an Error message from Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode

I have seen [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/13110/223943) answer, which tells about copying a warning message(Which also does not work), however I always have to type that again in browser, How do i copy it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always just right-clicked onto the warning message and selected Copy. This then places it on the clipboard and is available for pasting into other apps.

Below are two *examples* of how the copied message looks on the clipboard (or when pasted somewhere else):

> /Users/Username/Documents/Projects/Username (Developer)/iPhone
>   Apps/Trivia Apps/Draft Versions/Trivia Apps/App name.xcodeproj Update
>   to recommended settings
>
> file:///Users/Username/Documents/Projects/Username%20(Developer)/iPhone%20Apps/Trivia%20Apps/Draft%20Versions/Trivia%20Apps/App%20name.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Username.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/App%20name.xcscheme:
>   warning: Missing file: /Users/Username/Documents/Projects/Username
>   (Developer)/iPhone Apps/Trivia Apps/Draft Versions/App
>   name.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Username.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/App
>   name.xcscheme is missing from working copy

**NOTE:** Both of the above were copied from warning messages generated in Xcode 8.2.1, although I have changed the real username and app name.

If I'm misunderstanding your question, please clarify/let me know.

Comment: I do the same thing as @Monomeeth and I get the same results.  It appears that just plain copy/paste works fine.